# Checking Fourier coefficients

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-series

I am struggling with the Fourier coefficients for a piecewise constant function:

Let

\begin{equation}
    f(\xi)=\begin{cases}
        2, \ \ \ \ -3\le \xi<-\frac{3}{2} \\
        1, \ \ \ \ -\frac{3}{2}\le \xi<\frac{1}{5} \\
        3, \ \ \ \ 0.2\le \xi<1 \\
        6, \ \ \ \ 1\le \xi\le3
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

be piecewise constant function on the symmetric interval $[-3,3]$.

Then I get, with $h_j=(\xi_j-\xi_{j-1})$ and have verified that **this is correct** with Mathematica:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\alpha_0=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^af(\xi)\text{d}\xi=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{j=1}^4\eta_j(h_j)={}\\
&\frac{1}{6}\bigg[\bigg(2(-\frac{3}{2}+3)\bigg)+(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3}{2})\bigg)+3(1-\frac{1}{5})+6(3-1)\bigg)\bigg] =\frac{191}{60}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But when calculate the $\alpha_k$ coefficient, which should be the same structure, only with $\cos\omega k\xi$ multiplied to  it, with $\omega=\frac{\pi k}{n}=\frac{\pi k}{4}$ (n must be 4, since there are 4 intervals in the piecewise function):

I get the incorrect result:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    &\alpha_k=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^af(\xi)\cos(\omega k \xi)\text{d}\xi=\frac{2}{\pi k}\sum_{j=1}^4\eta_j\sin\bigg(\omega k \frac{h_j}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\omega k\frac{\xi_j+\xi_{j-1}}{2}\bigg)={}\\
    &\frac{2}{\pi k}\bigg[2\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k \frac{(-\frac{3}{2}+3)}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k\frac{(-\frac{3}{2}-3)}{2}\bigg)+\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k \frac{(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3}{2})}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k\frac{(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{3}{2})}{2}\bigg)+{}\\
    &3\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k \frac{(1-\frac{1}{5})}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k\frac{(1+\frac{1}{5})}{2}\bigg)+6\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k \frac{(3-1)}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{4} k\frac{(3+1)}{2}\bigg)\bigg] ={}\\
    &\frac{2}{\pi k}\bigg[6 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k^2}{4}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k^2}{2}\right)+3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k^2}{10}\right) \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  k^2}{20}\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi  k^2}{16}\right) \cos \left(\frac{9 \pi  k^2}{16}\right)+{}\\
    &\sin \left(\frac{17 \pi  k^2}{80}\right) \cos \left(\frac{13 \pi  k^2}{80}\right)\bigg]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But how can it be incorrect? The formula is correct indeed.

Or have I misunderstood something here?

What is the right set of calculation steps?

Thanks

Comment: Check to make sure Mathematica's definition for the Fourier coefficients (see the note about `FourierParameters` under "Details & Options" [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSeries.html)) matches the definition you're using.

Comment: This computational part is fine, that is the right reference and I use that, $n=20$. But when I want to solve using the formula which is also confirmed to be correct, the results is wrong. My suspicion is that $\omega$ wrong? But else than that, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sine-cosine form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Sine-cosine_form) of the Fourier series for

$$f(\xi)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -3\leq \xi \leq -\frac{3}{2} \\
 1 & -\frac{3}{2}\leq \xi <\frac{1}{5} \\
 3 & \frac{1}{5}\leq \xi <1 \\
 6 & 1\leq \xi \leq 3 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$

is given by

$$f(\xi)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^K \left(a_n \cos\left(\frac{n \pi \xi}{3}\right)+b_n \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \xi}{3}\right)\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

where

$$a_0=\frac{1}{6} \int_{-3}^3 f(\xi) \, d\xi=\frac{191}{60}\tag{3}$$

$$a_n=\frac{1}{3} \int\limits_{-3}^3 f(\xi) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n \xi}{3}\right) \, d\xi=-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)+3 \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)+2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{15}\right)-8 \sin(\pi n)}{\pi n}\tag{4}$$

$$b_n=\frac{1}{3} \int_\limits{-3}^3 f(\xi) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n \xi}{3}\right) \, d\xi=\frac{-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+3 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{3}\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{15}\right)-4 \cos (\pi  n)}{\pi  n}\tag{5}$$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates the Fourier series for $f(\xi)$ defined in formula (2) above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(\xi)$ defined in formula (1) above where formula (2) above is evaluated at $K=50$.

[image: Illustration of formula (3) and formula (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (3) for $f(\xi)$ (orange) overlaid on formula (1) for $f(\xi)$ (blue)

Comment: I checked your result, and it does not show how you go from a_n to the result. This is needed to understand the mechanism behind your calculations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to compute the integral in formula (4)? You can compute the integral in formula (4) by integrating piecewise as shown [here on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%2F6+%28Integrate%5B2+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C-3%2F2%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5B1+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2F2%2C1%2F5%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5B3+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2F5%2C1%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5B6+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2C3%7D%5D%29) where I substituted $x$ for $\xi$.

Comment: Originally I defined $f(\xi)$ as a [Piecewise](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) function in Mathematica as illustrated in formula (1), and then used Mathematica to calculated $a_n$ exactly as defined in the integral in formula (4).

Comment: I can't see what happens between $a_n$ and the result. Can you show your partial integrals? I give you 100 for that. There should be an integral for each indicator function, in order to be complete.

Comment: Did you not look at this [WolframAlpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%2F6+%28Integrate%5B2+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C-3%2F2%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5B1+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2F2%2C1%2F5%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5B3+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2F5%2C1%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5B6+Cos%5B2+Pi+n+x%2F6%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2C3%7D%5D%29) that I referenced in my first comment above which illustrates the four integrals?

Comment: As I mentioned above, Mathematica is also smart enough to break up a single integral of a piecewise function into multiple integrals which was my original approach illustrated in formula (4).